# How to query for nested array in php and laravel using mongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5.4

I'm using MongoDB with PHP's own driver and I have saved multiple arrays under main document. Structure looks like this:

```
[
  {
    _id: 5,
    unique: true,
    name: "Joseph",
    password: "mangalore"
  },
  {
    _id: 9,
    unique: true,
    name: "John",
    password: {
      passcode1: 1,
      passcode2: 2
    }
  }
]
```

**Note:** I want to fetch the data where **passcode2 > 1**

**Note:** Can u please show me both php and laravel code

**My code is**

```
$id = DB::connection('mongodb')
     ->collection('login2')
     ->where(array('password.passcode2','>',2))
     ->get();       

return $id;
```